What is the meaning of "interval $\langle 1, v_1 \rangle$"?
I read from the paper On Statistically Convergent Sequences of Real Numbers (PDF link via dml.cz), by Tibor Šalát (Mathematica Slovaka, 1980), of which I provide an excerpt (from page $141$) below.

for each $n \geq v_j \ (j = 1, 2, \ldots)$.
Let us construct the set $K$ as follows: Each natural number of the interval $\langle 1, v_1 \rangle$ belongs to $K$, further, any natural number of the interval $\langle v_j, v_{j+1} \rangle$ belongs to $K$ if and only if it belongs to $K_j \ (j = 1, 2, \ldots)$.
According to $(3)$, $(4)$ for each $n$, $v_j \leq n < v_{j+1}$ we get

I have a problem with understanding the symbol $\langle 1, v \rangle$ for the interval.
Is that a closed or an open interval? I haven't seen this before.

Could you link to the paper? Maybe the context gives away how that interval is defined. Apart from the question of which if any of its endpoints are elements, there's also the question of whether it's defined to be the integers only or a standard real interval.

As far as I know, the correct notation for an interval is $[a,b]$, so this notation might be simply wrong.

@J.G. T. ˇ Sal´at, On statistically convergent sequences of real numbers, Math. Slovaca, 30
(1980), 139–150.

$v_j$'s are natural numbers here.

in the paper there is mo any explation about them. I am trying to understand by context now.

https://www.dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/136236/MathSlov_30-1980-2_6.pdf

@JMP yes, this is. my question is in page 141

AFAIK (alas, I have no written sources at hand, and a quick search through pl/en/de Wikipedia brought no confirmation, either) this is a notation for closed interval, common in the area of Soviet/Russian influence in Europe some decades ago. Which the cited work seems to fit (published in Slovakia, 1980).

@CiaPan ok. Thank you.

As I mentioned in my comment, the symbol was in use in the Eastern European mathematical literature in twentieth century. So far I haven't found a solid reference, but here is the very first version of the 'interval' article from Wikipedia in Polish:

przedział domknięty o końcach a i b jest to przedział otwarty z dodanymi końcami (tj. punktami a i b). Notacja: [a,b], [a;b] lub <a,b>.
(rough transl. 'a closed interval is an open interval with its ends added ...')
https://pl.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Przedzia%C5%82_(matematyka)&oldid=65550
published in January 2003

The symbol has been deleted from the article in April 2006 (link: https://pl.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Przedzia%C5%82_%28matematyka%29&diff=prev&oldid=3076186)
The same symbol is still present in the Czech Wikipedia article:

$ \langle a, b \rangle = \{ x \,|\, a \le x \le b \} $
https://cs.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Interval_(matematika)&oldid=20329471
published in August 2021
section Typy intervalů

